# .net core Url.Action mock, how to?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq

How to mock Url.Action during testing controller action?

I'm trying to unit test my asp.net core controller action.
Logic of action has Url.Action and I need to mock it to complete test but I can't find right solution.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**
this is my method in controller that I need to test.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(EmailConfirmationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

            if (user == null) return RedirectToAction("UserNotFound");
            if (await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)) return RedirectToAction("IsAlreadyConfirmed");

            var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Confirm", "EmailConfirmation", new { userId = user.Id, token }, HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

            await _emailService.SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user, callbackUrl);

            return RedirectToAction("EmailSent");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I have problem with mocking this part:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Confirm", "EmailConfirmation", new { userId = user.Id, token }, HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

Comment: provide [mcve] of method under test and how you have tried to test it so far

Comment: @Nkosi, thank you! I update my post

Comment: I would love to know if you resolved this issue and if so how you resolved it.

Comment: @RianMostert, I solved my issue! Please read my answer and mark it if it is solved your problem.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Finally I found solution!

When you are mocking UrlHelper you need to mock only base method **Url.Action(UrlActionContext context)** because all helper methods actually use it.

```
        var mockUrlHelper = new Mock<IUrlHelper>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockUrlHelper
            .Setup(
                x => x.Action(
                    It.IsAny<UrlActionContext>()
                )
            )
            .Returns("callbackUrl")
            .Verifiable();

        _controller.Url = mockUrlHelper.Object;
```

Also! I have problem because of null in HttpContext.Request.Scheme. You need to mock HttpContext

```
_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
```

Comment: What can I say, this is the "official" Moq strategy using asp.net core.
Thanks @vladimir-rodchenko

Comment: Spent an entire afternoon trawling through the internet, but only your solution works (and actually makes sense). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I added

```
var urlHelperMock = new Mock<IUrlHelper>();
urlHelperMock
  .Setup(x => x.Action(It.IsAny<UrlActionContext>()))
  .Returns((UrlActionContext uac) =>
    $"{uac.Controller}/{uac.Action}#{uac.Fragment}?"
    + string.Join("&", new RouteValueDictionary(uac.Values).Select(p => p.Key + "=" + p.Value)));
controller.Url = urlHelperMock.Object;
```

To my generic Controller setup. Which is a bit roughnready but means I can test any controller logic that generates links.